# Starting Elasticsearch in Linux Shared hosting - Hostgator for Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, memory, linux

I have upgraded my magento version to Magento 2.4.6. I have tried installing elasticsearch 7 and elasticsearch 8 in my linux shared hosting in Hostagor. I am ending in error of could not allocate space.

I have updating jvm.options and also created a new file under jvm.otpions.d for changing the -Xms -Xmx

values to higher value like 8Gb and also tried keeping it to 256m as well. Neither of them worked. Can anyone help me with this what way i could resolve this issue?

I tried all the values to update -Xms, -Xmx values in jvm.options file.

[image]